# Save updated list of entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, savechanges

I get list of DTOs through API.

Then i map them to Entities.

DTO looks like :

```
public class BrandDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public static Brand MapToModel(BrandDTO model)
    {
        var retModel = new Brand
                       {
                           Name = model.Name,
                           Deleted = model.Deleted,
                           BrandId = model.Id
                       };
        return retModel;
    }

    public static IList<Brand> MapToModel(IEnumerable<BrandDTO> models)
    {
        return models.Select(MapToModel).ToList();
    }
}
```

Entity looks like :

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How i get Models from DTOs (brands input param):

```
var brandsModels = BrandDTO.MapToModel(brands);
var updatedBrands = brandsModels.Where(b => existingBrandsIds.Contains(b.BrandId));

await repo.Update(updatedBrands);// which just make await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

As I understand, entities aren't updated cause I didn't "connect" updated entity to entity in context. Am I right? If so  how can i do it and is there way to make it for collection of entities?

Comment: This should help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576330/Attaching-detached-POCO-to-EF-DbContext-simple-and

Comment: @CountZero, is it good solution in case big data? i am talking about using foreach loop in that post. Or there are only one solution?

Comment: ORMS tend to be a terrible choice for big data. While I know nHibernate has some bulk update functionality (not sure about EF) it will always be slower than raw SQL. If you are just updating and not using the created entities anywhere would it not make more sense to use something like Dapper and avoid the overhead and complexity of EF?